# How to use InAppBrowser in Ionic 2 application

Tags: android, ionic-framework

I am developing a Ionic 2 application and targeting both android and iOS platforms. I am using InAppBrowser to navigate to Office 365 login page, once user logs in to office 365, I receive some data with the callback URL. This data is passed to a web service which logs the user to the application. Now, the office 365 logging and receiving the data process is done successfully. On loadstop event I am fetching the data from the URL and closing the browser. When the browser is closed I come back to my application, and give a call to the web service. But somehow after I get back to my application with the data, the call to web service is not made. I have to idea what is wrong, can someone please help .

Thanks in advance